# PHP strip image from description

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to strip the image from the xml feed below, but so far without luck.
I used the following code ([PHP get img src from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666234/php-get-img-src-from-xml)), but it does not give a result.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(1);
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
$dom->formatOutput = True;
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

foreach( $xpath->query( 'channel/item/description' ) as $node )
{
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTML( $node->nodeValue );
    $src = $html->getElementsByTagName( 'img' )->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    echo $src.PHP_EOL ."<br/>";
}
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction or tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
<item>
<title>
Menschenversuche mit Abgasen: „Ein vertretbares geringes Risiko“
</title>
<description>
<img width=190 height=107 border=0 title="Hier fanden die Versuche statt – ganz freiwillig: Uniklinik der RWTH Aachen" alt="Hier fanden die Versuche statt – ganz freiwillig: Uniklinik der RWTH Aachen" src=http://media0.faz.net/ppmedia/aktuell/wirtschaft/1493413458/1.5429400/article_teaser/hier-fanden-die-versuche-statt.jpg /><p>Blutabnahme, Lungenfunktionstest, dann in einer „Anlage“ Stickoxid einatmen. Ein Student, der an den viel diskutierten Menschenversuchen an der RWTH Aachen teilnahm, erzählte nun, wie es im Detail zuging – allerdings unter den Augen seiner Professoren.</p>
</description>
<link>
http://www.faz.net/aktuell/beruf-chance/campus/ein-student-und-seine-professoren-erzaehlen-von-den-menschenversuchen-mit-abgasen-15429186.html
</link>
<pubDate>Fri, 02 Feb 2018 13:44:11 +0100</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.faz.net/-gyq-96p8i</guid>
</item>
```

Here is my current ugly workaround, I would believe there is a nicer solution though:

```
description2 = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
preg_match('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', $description2, $image4);
preg_match('/(src[^>]+>)/i', $image4[0], $image2);
$image2 = $image2[0];
$image2 = rtrim( $image2, " />");
$image2 = ltrim( $image2, "src=");
```

UPDATE: Here is my current version:

**I am not able to directly load the rss feed into Dom, any hint in the right direction is appreciated here.**

```
$feed = "http://www.faz.net/rss/aktuell/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
$dom_xml = dom_import_simplexml($xml);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(1);
$dom->formatOutput = True;
$dom_xml = $dom->importNode($dom_xml, true);
$dom_xml = $dom->appendChild($dom_xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

foreach( $xpath->query( 'channel/item/description' ) as $node )
{
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTML( $node->nodeValue );
    $src = $html->getElementsByTagName( 'img' )->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    echo $src.PHP_EOL ."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: What is your output and what would you expect?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is just going to echo out a list of *src* data from the images..?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thnx Magnus, am a Newbie here; i shortened the code in the question. What I need to extract is the url of the image in the <description> tag.

Comment: Why don't you just `str_replace()` that whole `<img width=190 height=107 border=0[...]versuche-statt.jpg />` with an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem in your xpath query. If you prepend two slashes to your query (select all nodes within the document that match the path ), you will get the results you expect.

```
$xpath->query( '//channel/item/description' )
```

I ran your code with that change and it worked.

EDIT: Full example using cURL below:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.faz.net/rss/aktuell/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$xml = curl_exec($ch);

if($xml===false)
{
    $curlErrorMsg = curl_error($ch);
    die('Unable to load feed: '.$curlErrorMsg);
}

curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$xmlLoaded = $dom->loadXML( $xml );

if(!$xmlLoaded)
{
    die('Invalid XML');
}

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

foreach( $xpath->query( '//channel/item/description' ) as $node )
{
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTML( $node->nodeValue );
    $src = $html->getElementsByTagName( 'img' )->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    echo $src.PHP_EOL ."<br/>";
}
```

See the [PHP cURL docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Rob, how can I make this work if I'm using a rss-feed. $xml = simplexml_load_file(feed-url) does not seem to work.

Comment: It sounds like the allow_url_fopen directive is set to no on your system. You can use cURL to get the feed contents as a string and get rid of simple_xml entirely. I've updated my answer above to include a working example of this.